# html5, js and css3 image crop tool

Tags: javascript, html, css, crop

I want to make a croping tool for images using html5, css3 and javascript (jQuery). I am having trouble in making the following: add a grey, alpha=0.5 overlay div/span/whatever over the image i want to crop with a hole div/span/whatever in the middle that shows the image's true colors. I want to be able to move this hole inside the grey mask, so event listeners will be set on this hole. Is this doable with html5 and css3? I don't care about the js code, that i will do on my own.

Thank you very much

Comment: Show us what you tried so far. Also, this site is not a code-for-me service.

Comment: This is possible using the canvas.

Comment: An ideea on how to acomplish this is having only one div (the hole) and dynamically changing it's borders dimensions to fit the image. The borders color will be the grey 0.5 alpha color

Edit: @PeterB. I haven't done anything worth showing yet. and i didn't request any code, just ideeas on how this can be acomplished

Comment: I would use a floating div with absolute positioning and listeners on it to move/ resize it, like a window. something [like this](http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/examples/kitchensink/#basic-window)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this example:

Then you just have to move the .hole position with jquery event (drag) or whatever.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.hole {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 99999px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  border-radius: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/51/Fox_Head.jpg" alt="" style="width: 30%;">
  <div class="hole"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

how about this:

1. wrapper with position:relative and overflow:hidden
2. image
3. absolute positioned rectangle with very large box-shadow and background transparent

```js
$( function() {
    $( ".mask" ).draggable();
  } );
```

```css
body{padding:4px;}
.wrap{width:300px;margin:auto;position:relative;overflow:hidden}

.wrap img{width:100%;display:block}
.mask{
  outline:1px solid white;
  cursor:move;
  position:absolute;
  top:20px;
  left:100px;
  width:80px;
  height:80px;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 900000px rgba(0,0,0,0.75)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrap">
  <div class="mask"></div>
  <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/460/300">
</div>
```

Comment: ;-( Jordi Flores was faster